# how to get the values for all matching keys from JSON in Java and Jackson parser

Tags: java, json

Given the Json I only get the values of the first array (Say for example I get only one value of "timestamp") with the following code below.

```
[    
        {
            "type": "Brand",
            "matchedProducts": [],
            "matchedIds": [
                "adidas",
                "adidas"
            ],
            "timestamp": 1440961761478
        },
        {
            "type": "Category",
            "matchedProducts": [
                1543669767
            ],
            "matchedIds": [],
            "timestamp": 1440962000467
        }

]
```

This is the method when I pass the above Json string as s and key as timestamp then I get only one timestamp. I want both. Can some one help me here please.

```
public static List<String> getValuesAsListFromJson2Lvl(String s, String key) throws ParseException, JSONException {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    String name = null;
    JSONObject obj;
    s = s.substring(s.indexOf("[")+1);
    s = s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf("]"));
    Logger.log("s:"+ s);
    obj = new JSONObject(s);
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    String valuesAsString = null;

    Logger.log("obj.toString():"+ obj.toString());


    if ("matchedIds".equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray(key);
        Logger.log("jsonArray.length() for key is:" + jsonArray.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            Logger.log("jsonArray.get(" + i + ")" + jsonArray.get(i));
            values.add((String) jsonArray.get(i));
        }
    } else if ("timestamp".equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {


         String tmp =  obj.getString(key);
        Logger.log("tmp:" + tmp);
        JSONObject jsonObject = obj.getJSONObject(key);
        Logger.log("jsonObject.get(" + key + ") :" + jsonObject.get(key));

        values.add((String) jsonObject.get(key));
    }

    return values;
}
```

}

Comment: `s = s.substring(s.indexOf("[")+1);` why on earth???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It return correct answer with code belows:

```
public static List<String> getValuesAsListFromJson2Lvl(String s, String key) throws  JSONException {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String value = jsonObject.get(key).toString();
        values.add(value);
    }
    return values;
}
```